# Bioshock 1/Playonlinux - can't turn 360°

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I'm trying to play this game through PlayOnLinux, the graphics and sound are fine. However, I can not make the character turn 360°.

I saw in WineHQ that this is a problem in an old version of wine:

> **Mouse is holding at the edge of the screen, can't turn 360.**
>
> Make a new text document called  mousewarpoverride.reg in your home
>   folder and add the follow content:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\DirectInput]
> "MouseWarpOverride"="force"
> ```
>
> Run the following code in Terminal:
>
> ```
> env WINEDEBUG="fixme-all" WINEPREFIX="(your-prefix)" wine regedit
> ```
>
> ~/mousewarpoverride.reg

I'm using the latest version of wine in PlayOnLinux and have this problem, and the solution is provided for a normal installation of wine.

How do I apply this solution in PlayOnLinux?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it.

Just going into **playonlinux > configure > wine > registry editor > file > import registry** fixed it.

More simple than I thought. Linux noob here :)